# how to insert newline after word in sql table in c#

Tags: c#, sql, newline

I am trying to insert New Line after word car but it is not working with folowing solution

1. `Char(13)` - not working
2. `Environment.NewLine` - when i use this it works but appends '(' this char in sql rows like 'Car ( Rate:2CR'
3. `\n\r` - not working

Code:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnCar", Car + "char(13)" + "Rate:2CR"; 
  //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnCar", Car + "\n\r" + "Rate:2CR"; 
  //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnCar", Car + Environment.NewLine + "Rate:2CR"; 

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Need output in sql table `ColumnCar` row value as follows:

```
Car
Rate:2cr
```

Note : here after Car there will be a newline and then Rate:2Cr will be added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the LoC `Car + "char(13)" + "Rate:2CR";` you will get a literal string `"char(13)"` between your 2 values, not a new line. If you want only a new line you can append `"\n"` or you can append the character equivalent `(char)10` of new line.

Now what character or string actually represents a new line might depend on your environment including the collation you are using. In simple ascii/ansi this will work. It might not be the same for another collation. As `@mhasan` pointed out it could also be different depending on the O/S.

Using characters

```
const char carriageReturn = (char) 13; // see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return
const char newLine = (char) 10;

var car = "some car";
var toInsert = car + newLine + "Rate:2CR";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnCar", toInsert);
```

This would also work and produce the same result:

```
var toInsert = car + "\n" + "Rate:2CR";
```

Comment: my mistake ,wrong char was appending thats why it was not working thanks Igor

Answer (score 1):

Use combination of newline and carriage return characters i.e. `char(13) + char(10)` for inserting new line in windows OS system.
For MAC its \r char(13) , for Linux its \n i.e. char(10) but for windows its combination of both.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code hope its working...

Make a string variable and store all value in variable..

ex: string abc=textbox1.text+" "+"Rate:2cr";
@ColumnCar=abc.tostring();

now put your code

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnCar",datatype);
cmd.executenonquery();

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine with unicode fields in a MS SQL-Server 2016 DB :

```
  string carString = $"Volvo{Environment.NewLine}Rate: 2CR";

  SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@ColumnCar", carString);
  command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

The '(' when you use Environment.NewLine must be another error somewhere else. What is Car in your code? A class instance? What does its ToString() expand to?

Don't use string1 + " " + string2 concatenation.
Use string.Format(), $"" - inline syntax (like above) or StringBuilder to build your strings.